# Reference to a column in the aggregation context may not appear outside of an aggregate function

Tags: kql

I need to build a query that calculates the percentage rate of each value of a category( in this case strategy) out of the total runs, across different time buckets.
I came up with the below query, however I get syntax error :

**Semantic error: Reference to a column 'total' in the aggregation context may not appear outside of an aggregate function.**

```
requests
| where timestamp between (startTime..endTime)
| extend strategy = tostring(customDimensions.QueryStrategy)
| summarize count() by strategy, bin(timestamp, 30m)
| join (requests 
| where timestamp between (startTime..endTime)
| summarize total = count() by bin(timestamp, 30m)) on timestamp
| project timestamp, strategy, count_, total = toint(total)
| summarize 100 *count()/total by strategy, timestamp
```

Comment: requests
| where timestamp between (startTime..endTime)
| extend strategy = tostring(customDimensions.QueryStrategy)
| summarize count() by strategy, bin(timestamp, 30m)
| join (requests 
| where timestamp between (startTime..endTime)
| summarize total = count() by bin(timestamp, 30m)) on timestamp
| project timestamp, strategy, count_, total = toint(total)
| summarize 100 *count()/total by strategy, timestamp

Comment: Don't post essential info in comments and especially not code. [Edit] your post, and put it between 2 lines each containing three backticks `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct way to achieve what you want:

```
// The following table literally represents a long calculation
// that ends up with an anonymous tabular value:
datatable (SomeInt:int, SomeSeries:string) [
  100, "Apple",
  200, "Banana",
]
// We now give this calculation a name ("X"):
| as X
// Having this name we can refer to it in the sub-expression
// "X | summarize sum(SomeInt)":
| extend Pct = 100 * bin(todouble(SomeInt) / toscalar(X | summarize sum(SomeInt)), 0.001)
```

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuredataexplorer#extend-a-table-by-a-percentage-of-the-total-calculation

Comment: You're welcome! Will appreciate if you accept the answer (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)).